# Problema de update en Mysql

Tags: mysqli, mysql-workbench

Este es un cursor el cual busca actualizar las llaves primarias por otras, estas claves primarias tienen que tener los 2 primeros datos ED de editorial, y tomar los primeros 3 caracteres del pais, los primeros 3 caracteres del nombre y con un contador colocar un numero, pero no puedo lograr el objetivo porque la clave primaria tiene que ser de 10 digitos y cuando coloca el valor del 1 al 9 queda un espacio y no logro hacer que quede "EDMEXali01" por ejemplo si no que me da de resulatado "EDMEXali1" y si le pongo el 0 de forma manual en el concat() pues me da error porque cuando llega al 10 supera el limite de caracteres del char (10) ayuda...

```
delimiter //
create procedure c ()
begin 
    declare ID char(10);
    declare p   varchar(30);
    declare n   varchar(30);
    declare ss   int ;
    declare fin integer default 0 ;
    declare coun cursor for select  count(*) from Editorial;
    declare cursor_n cursor for select substring(nombre,1,3)from Editorial;
    declare cursor_p cursor for select substring(pais,1,3 )from Editorial;
    declare cursor_s cursor for select codigo from Editorial ;
    declare continue handler for not found set fin =1;
    open cursor_p;
    open cursor_n;
    open cursor_s;
    open coun;
    Ciclo: loop 
        fetch cursor_p into p ;
        fetch cursor_n into n;
        fetch cursor_s into ID;
        fetch coun into ss;
        if fin =1 then 
            leave   Ciclo;
        end if;
        update libreria.Editorial set codigo = concat('ED',p,n,0+ss) 
        where codigo = ID ;
         update libreria.Editorial set codigo = concat('ED',p,n,ss) 
        where codigo = ID and  ss > 10;
    end loop Ciclo; 
    close cursor_p ;
    close cursor_n ;
    close cursor_s ;
    close coun;
end //
```

Comment: Prueba a declarar `ss` así: **`declare ss INT(2) ZEROFILL;`**

Comment: vale lo pruebo y confirmo si funciona, gracias

Comment: perfecto muchisimas gracias A. Cedano me fue muy util

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En MySQL puedes usar `ZEROFILL` en las declaraciones, en cuyo caso te llenará con `0` a la izquierda los valores.

Sabiendo eso, puedes declarar `ss` así:

```
declare ss INT(2) ZEROFILL;
```